# android.widget.TableRow cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

Tags: android, casting

in my code i get the following error:

`android.widget.TableRow cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView`

The error-log jumps to the following line in the code:

```
mDateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.datumGesetztText);
```

What does this mean?!

Greets

Answer (score 0):

It is evident from the error message the 'R.id.datumGesetztText' is table row not a textView. Make sure ...view.xml has correct type defined for this field.

Comment: i checked it already...
tablerow -> android:id="@+id/datumRow"
textview -> android:id="@+id/datumGesetztText"